# Create certificate keystore file AES 128

Tags: certificate, aes, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to create certificate key-store file with command line but it gives me an exception:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool.exe -genkey -alias srccodes -keyalg AES -
keystore C:\srccodes.jks -keysize 128
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Cannot derive signature algorithm
```

Comment: Try [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 10):

`-genkey` option is for generating a public key and associated private key, so it only works with asymmetric algorithm (AES is symmetric so you can't use `-genkey` with it).

Use `-genseckey` instead. Note also that `JKS` can not store non public-key pairs, so you must use `JCEKS` format, to specify this add `-storeType JCEKS`, finally your command must be:

`keytool.exe -genseckey-alias srccodes -keyalg AES -keystore C:\srccodes.jceks -keysize 128 -storeType JCEKS`

For more info take a look at: [Keytool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks you, i have created store file success, but i have another problem. Its description too long and i insert in new answer, please read and help me.:)

Comment: @LêĐứcNguyên about your new question you can not post it as an answer besides I think that you must ask this as first because the answer it's a bit different, so you must ask a new question however I give you the answer if you want to configure SSL in tomcat you need and RSA key not AES, to generate this with keytool use this command: `keytool.exe -genkey -alias srccodes -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\srccodes.jks -keysize 2048`. If the answers helps you please accept it `:)`.

Comment: I have been create store file by RSA, but when run tomcat at port 8433, it have notification certificate not verification. So i must create a keystore file 128bit or more than.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean with "create keystore file 128bit or more than"? if you take a look at my comment I specify a `-keysize 2048` for the RSA key.

Comment: @LêĐứcNguyên This answer rings true to me. Please accept if this answers your *original* question. Note that it is not very sporting to also request a consultancy session on top of an answer.

Comment: @albciff : Saved the day. Thanks

Comment: @guarav happy to help `:)`